# why dose create-react-app not working in ios < 10?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

- node v11.10.0
- react 16.8.6

I used create-react-app to create my projectv but when I run `npm run build`, I use IOS<10 open in Safari, it can't open, give me an error as above.

Comment: Why not working? Because [they did not support](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/supported-browsers-features).

Comment: Make peace with new technologies :) It is like windows users who still use IE11

Comment: Can I some polyfills to solve this problem? I need you help, please